# Conditions for scattering of evanescent waves?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, scattering

In [this](https://books.google.ch/books?id=9rZTz2WC7OoC&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=evanescent+wave++scatter+powder&source=bl&ots=UrDGJ_HOgQ&sig=ACfU3U0IPC2ne7dIkzp5_l6KFeaIHoYVFA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEnYyxiYzuAhWC26QKHXcTCTIQ6AEwEnoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=evanescent%20wave%20%20scatter%20powder) monograph internal reflection spectroscopy, the author makes the case that the evanescent wave cannot decouple from the surface and be scattered away from the interface (even in the presence of powdered samples in close proximity).

However, we also know that different optical measurement techniques like [total internal reflection microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection_microscopy), [frustrated total internal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection#Frustrated_TIR) use the fact that evanescent waves are scattered.

Am I missing some qualifications from the first monograph that makes that statement (that evanescent waves do not scatter when in contact with powders) correct?